# Ansible Jinja template undefined variable loop

Tags: templates, ansible, jinja2

How to set this template task not fail when datacenter_misc is undefined ? template file is jinja2 based.

```
{% for host in groups[datacenter ~ "_opb_docker"]+groups[datacenter ~ "_misc"] %}
        - {{ host }}:9100
{% endfor %}
```

Currently if datacenter_misc is undefined the playbook fails. Bear in mind datacenter is also a variable. Basically hosts group name is datacenter_misc.

Thanks!

Comment: Use the solution based on the other answer than accepted under the dup-target.

Comment: @techraf I have seen this solution. However it doesnt't work for me, because (if I use the example you quoted) the consul variable has to be enabled for host I am running playbook against. 

Instead, variable should be coming from hosts part of group datacenter_misc

Comment: Yes. You cannot copy and paste the code from the other answer, you need to apply it to your case (by changing variable names etc.).

Comment: I did change variable name. Problem is variable has to be defined for host that is part of a group, not host I am running playbook against (which is what this example does).

Comment: So change the variable to refer to the host that is part of a group, not host you are running playbook against.